# Redis keys deleting automatically

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using Redis from Amazon ElastiCache. When I am creating keys its getting deleted automatically in random time intervals, ranging from 1 to 40 seconds

```
**************:6379> set testkey 1
OK
**************:6379> get testkey
"1"
**************:6379> get testkey
"1"
**************:6379> get testkey
"1"
**************:6379> get testkey
(nil)
```

Even if i set a expire its still not honoring that time

```
**************:6379> set testkey 1
OK
**************:6379> expire testkey 1000
(integer) 1
**************:6379> ttl testkey
(integer) 996
**************:6379> ttl testkey
(integer) 994
**************:6379> ttl testkey
(integer) -2
**************:6379> get testkey
(nil)
```

I tried to search through articles but could not find a solid solution. Please help me or point me in the right direction

My INFO ALL output

```
# Server
redis_version:4.0.10
redis_git_sha1:0
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:0
redis_mode:standalone
os:Amazon ElastiCache
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:0.0.0
process_id:1
run_id:9b47409883d74bd6226f6da83049f0299306942f
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:1532242
uptime_in_days:17
hz:10
lru_clock:8988158
executable:-
config_file:-

# Clients
connected_clients:1584
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:41694472
used_memory_human:39.76M
used_memory_rss:45117440
used_memory_rss_human:43.03M
used_memory_peak:46522760
used_memory_peak_human:44.37M
used_memory_peak_perc:89.62%
used_memory_overhead:33041108
used_memory_startup:3662144
used_memory_dataset:8653364
used_memory_dataset_perc:22.75%
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:436469760
maxmemory_human:416.25M
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.08
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:54915489
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1534182572
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:6594931
total_commands_processed:311024303
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:345
total_net_input_bytes:47103888444
total_net_output_bytes:1706056764081
instantaneous_input_kbps:20.91
instantaneous_output_kbps:2093.84
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:2573
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:23866292
keyspace_misses:234233574
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:ab5f0fbbecf06195be44983dbde289e2d0725335
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:8175.90
used_cpu_user:5509.23
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

# Commandstats
cmdstat_ping:calls=434117,usec=366264,usec_per_call=0.84
cmdstat_set:calls=6641,usec=23175,usec_per_call=3.49
cmdstat_config:calls=3,usec=55,usec_per_call=18.33
cmdstat_del:calls=20684265,usec=38010326,usec_per_call=1.84
cmdstat_keys:calls=1,usec=34,usec_per_call=34.00
cmdstat_exists:calls=458,usec=899,usec_per_call=1.96
cmdstat_expire:calls=4229654,usec=9412184,usec_per_call=2.23
cmdstat_flushdb:calls=27478,usec=14170960,usec_per_call=515.72
cmdstat_get:calls=248088801,usec=1086400958,usec_per_call=4.38
cmdstat_setex:calls=20257389,usec=63289845,usec_per_call=3.12
cmdstat_ttl:calls=2202549,usec=3262291,usec_per_call=1.48
cmdstat_getset:calls=7808523,usec=25766044,usec_per_call=3.30
cmdstat_select:calls=6594457,usec=6533380,usec_per_call=0.99
cmdstat_info:calls=689967,usec=219565932,usec_per_call=318.23

# SSL
ssl_enabled:no
ssl_connections_to_previous_certificate:0
ssl_connections_to_current_certificate:0
ssl_current_certificate_not_before_date:(null)
ssl_current_certificate_not_after_date:(null)
ssl_current_certificate_serial:0

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=4604,expires=4604,avg_ttl=172095914
```

Comment: Please share the output from `INFO ALL`, but my guess is that something is deleting that key... e.g. an explicit `DEL` or `FLUSHALL`

Comment: @ItamarHaber I update my question with output.

Comment: @ItamarHaber you are right i see cmdstat_flushdb increasing and i calculated its increasing every minute. But we are not calling any flush from out application in certain of it. Could this be amazon aws policy?

Comment: Open a connection and monitor the output of CLIENT LIST to try and find the culprit... I don't know how AWS provides their Redis-like service so you should approach their support about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using laravel framework, and for some reason we are running `artisan clear:cache` every minute as pointed out by @himanshu gupta.

I removed the cron and everything is normal